# Jenkins (formerly Hudson) Plot Plugin: Illegible Font

Tags: java, fonts, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

The text within the plots generated by Jenkins' Plot plugin is illegible, as it uses a very small cursive font.  It appears as though I am missing a Java font used by this plugin; however, I have no idea how to install or find such fonts.  I'm using OpenJDK 1.6.0, and have JRE 6u23 installed.

It's the same issue experienced at the [Labels-are-unreadable-in-charts](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/JIRA-Created-HUDSON-6186-Labels-are-unreadable-in-charts-td1754042.html), but much to my dismay, the user did not post the solution after figuring out how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps you out or not, but OpenJDK is known to have font rendering issues for Java.

You'll see a bunch of stuff here on [Google Search Results](http://www.google.com/search?q=openjdk%20font%20issue&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

I just tested an application yesterday that had blurred fonts with OpenJDK but ran fine with Sun JDK.

Unless you have a restriction on using Sun's JDK, I would try that and see if it works..

Comment: Thanks so much!!  That did the trick.  This has been so frustrating, so I am very grateful for your help.  For anyone else who is having this problem, I downloaded the JRE/JDK RPM packages from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.