# jenkins project's axes labes in graphs are blurred

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[image]

[image]

I just started using jenkins for my project a few days ago, and I just found that axes of the graphs in project home are all blurred (all the other graphs, including findbugs and checkstyle warnings, too).

It was okay when I only had two or three builds, so is there a problem in rendering characters for graphs in jenkins, or any other related libraries?

And what can I do?

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653888/jenkins-formerly-hudson-plot-plugin-illegible-font) post, which might explain your problem a bit more. The short answer is you probably are lacking some fonts on the server side.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762928/jfreechart-strange-rendering-headless-redhat) is another thread to look at.

Comment: Thanks you so much! and the link (one of the links in the links you gave me i guess) http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/fonts-in-junit-trend-graphs-are-unreadable-td4562710.html just solved my problem!